# dropboxd Syntax error: ")" unexpected

Tags: bash, terminal, ubuntu-12.04, dropbox, webserver

I am trying to install dropbox(**x86_64 version**) on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS,
with this installation guide:

http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/install-dropbox-in-an-entirely-text-based-linux-environment

But when i get to step 6. Run dropboxd

```
~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

I get the error:

```
/home/jacob/.dropbox-dist/dropbox: 1: /home/jacob/.dropbox-dist/dropbox: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

What is causing this error? I'm not a bash expert but this seems valid to me:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Copyright 2008-2013 Dropbox, Inc.
#
# Environment script for the dropbox executable.
PAR=$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")
OLD_LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export OLD_LD_LIBRARY_PATH
exec "$PAR"/dropbox "$@"
```

**Sys info:**

Linux 12.04 Ubuntu LTS
ppc64
Linux dev 3.2.0-55-powerpc64-smp #85-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 2 15:28:59 UTC 2013 ppc64 ppc64 ppc64 GNU/Linux

I would greatly appreciate any help,
Thanks

Comment: What file are you quoting here? The error is in line one of `~/.dropbox-dist/dropbox` (not in `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question you state that you are trying to install the **x86_64** version of Dropbox.  However, in your system info, your kernel is described as **ppc64**.  These are not the same, and x86_64 binaries will not run on a ppc64 kernel.

Comment: Is there a dropbox version for kernel ppc64? Or maby some other software solutions i am not aware off? Anyhow Thanks for answering

Comment: I haven't ever looked for a PPC version, but since Apple dropped PPC several years ago its usage in the consumer market is pretty much gone, so I doubt they have something.  You might search around for something written in Java, Python or another scripting language that could be run independent of the platform.  If you have some programming knowledge you can also look into use the [Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers)